# .NET 6 set Newtonsoft.Json default options with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, autofac, .net-6.0

I am currently refatoring my .NET 6 WebAPI. While refactoring i switched to use Autofac as my DI-Framework.

To let my controllers not return null values I use newtonsoft json with the follwing options:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddDefaultJsonOptions();
```

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddDefaultJsonOptions(this IMvcBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
}
```

With autofac I changed the registration of my controllers to:

```
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<Autofac.ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
{
    ...

    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(executingAssembly);

    ...
});
```

But how can I change the default json serialization options now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awesomeness of ASP.NET Core being totally open source is you can [hit the repo yourself](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore) and do some spelunking to figure out what these methods do and then track down how to solve issues like this.

In this case, let's see [what `AddControllers` actually does](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f9ae0f5d30be2de3c0de61b5673bd8873231d70a/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L91):

```cs
public static IMvcBuilder AddControllers(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    var builder = AddControllersCore(services);
    return new MvcBuilder(builder.Services, builder.PartManager);
}
```

Looks like there's a lot hidden in `AddControllersCore`, so [we can scroll down to that](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f9ae0f5d30be2de3c0de61b5673bd8873231d70a/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L145):

```cs
private static IMvcCoreBuilder AddControllersCore(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // This method excludes all of the view-related services by default.
    var builder = services
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddApiExplorer()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddCors()
        .AddDataAnnotations()
        .AddFormatterMappings();

    if (MetadataUpdater.IsSupported)
    {
        services.TryAddEnumerable(
            ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IActionDescriptorChangeProvider, HotReloadService>());
    }

    return builder;
}
```

Interesting. So `AddControllers` doesn't actually add *the literal controllers* to the set of services - it adds the things *needed to execute controllers*. Why is that?

I'll fast-forward a bit - it's because **controllers aren't resolved as services by default.** Surprise! What actually happens is that the controller *parameters* are resolved, but the *controller itself* gets created via reflection, with the resolved parameters passed to the constructor. If you actually want controllers *to be resolved* (like, to support property injection or something), [you need to use `AddControllersAsServices`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f9ae0f5d30be2de3c0de61b5673bd8873231d70a/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L155) (This is also [in the Autofac documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services).)

In fact, that `RegisterApiControllers` method you're using isn't even for ASP.NET Core - it's for [ASP.NET Web API](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html), which isn't in .NET 6. You really need to be checking out [ASP.NET Core integration](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) and definitely *not* using any of the classic ASP.NET and Web API stuff in your refactoring. It's not mix-and-match. It's all .NET Core / ASP.NET Core.

So, to answer the question, how do you *both* register your controllers *and* get your JSON options?

**Keep doing what you were doing.**

```cs
builder.Services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddControllersAsServices()
  .AddDefaultJsonOptions();
```

If you really do want to manually register controllers with Autofac, you could *re-register* them (*after* you call `AddControllersAsServices`) but you'll register them as themselves.

```cs
builder.Host
  .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Services
  .AddControllers()
  .AddControllersAsServices()
  .AddDefaultJsonOptions();
builder.Host
  .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(b => {
    b.RegisterType<MyController>().PropertiesAutowired();
  });
```

But, again, unless you're specifically doing something to override how the controller is registered, like needing to set up a lambda or property injection or something, `AddControllersAsServices` will cover it.

**You do need the `UseServiceProviderFactory` call if you want Autofac as your container.** Otherwise you get the default Microsoft container, even if you call `ConfigureContainer<T>`.